Tile grout in shower floor pan
The builder's crew was sloppy in parts of their work. I have what I think are bits of grout dried in between the textured surface of the walk in shower floor pan. I tried a scrub brush but it only released a bit of it.
How do I get this stuff removed safely so my shower doesn't look worn out when it's brand new?


If the job was just done it needs to be brought to the attention of the builder. Then it is his problem to solve.

What's going on in the bottom, right corner? What's that notch?

Once grout dries/sets it is very hard to remove.  If not bonded well to the surface, a plastic scraper might remove it.  If bonded well, then the big guns(sanders/grinders/chisels) will probably be needed.  If needed, then lack of damage go way down.
